# Huffman tree, is this correct?

Tags: huffman-code

I'm trying to make create a correct huffman tree and was wondering if this was correct. The top number is the frequency/weight and the bottom number is the ASCII code. The string is 
"hhiiiisssss". If I entered this into a text file, there would be only one LF correct? I'm not sure why my program is reading in two.

```
                                14
                                -1
                            /       \
                           9         5
                           -1        s(115)
                         /   \
                         5   4
                        -1   i(105)
                       /   \
                      3     2
                  h(104)   LF(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a text file there would only be one LF if there is only one line of text, correct.

Something else is wrong though. There are only two 'h' in your string but your tree shows three, and a total of 14 characters. I'm guessing it's a typo?

Aside from that it looks ok and your huffman codes would be (depending on whether you pick '0' for left or right):

```
s:   1
i:   01
LF:  001
h:   000
```